# How to split a Ruby array into subarrays of unequal size using a delimiter

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following array:

```
arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Without changing the order of the values, I need to subdivide `arr` into smaller arrays at every occurrence of `0`, such that the result would be:

```
arr = [ [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1], [0], [0, 1] ]
```

If `arr` were a string, I could use `.split("0")` and then prepend the delimiter to each subarray. What would be the most efficient equivalent to `.split()` in plain Ruby for arrays?

Comment: I don't really understand the question yet, but in general, if you're dealing with tree-like structures, recursion is often the best general solution.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, along with "[mcve]". Without code it looks like you're asking us to write a tutorial or to write the code for you, neither of which are on-topic.

Comment: That seems like a complicated use of `Array`. I would ponder whether there is a more appropriate data type to use when **parsing**, rather than convert an array into a nested array. Without knowing where this would be consumed its hard to advise. But I'd look at building a tree structure using objects. E.g. each line becomes its own object, with knowledge of its parent and child objects. Appreciate you need to preserve order too, which could be done using the child objects as an array of objects.

Comment: Great idea. Objects would solve the problem in this instance. Thank you! (Even if it isn't the best approach, I'm still curious as to how one would subdivide an array the way I wanted to, and have edited my original question accordingly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Enumerable#slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) does this exact thing:

```
arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1]
p arr.slice_before(0).to_a
# => [[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1], [0], [0, 1]]
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/FBhg

Comment: Somehow I was thinking of this exact method and failed to apply it correctly. Good catch.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Don't know how I missed this method in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Since [ActiveSupport defines an Array#split method in Ruby](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/grouping.rb#L91-L106), we can use it as a starting point:

```
class Array
  def split(value = nil)
    arr = dup
    result = []
    if block_given?
      while (idx = arr.index { |i| yield i })
        result << arr.shift(idx)
        arr.shift
      end
    else
      while (idx = arr.index(value))
        result << arr.shift(idx)
        arr.shift
      end
    end
    result << arr
  end
end

# then, using the above to achieve your goal:
arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1]
arr.split(0).map { |sub| sub.unshift(0) }
# => [[0], [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1], [0], [0, 1]]
```

Note that your verbal phrasing of the algorithm (split and prepend) is what is happening here, but your expected output is different (there's an additional zero because of the way `split` works).

Do you want to *split before each zero*? For this you could use `slice_before`.

Do you want to *split but drop empty arrays*? This could be done with a quick `compact` before prepending, but you would lose the `[0]` subarray.

Do you want to *split but drop the first element if empty*?

Do you want to *split on `/0+/`*?

Comment: Jordan beat you to it; `slice_before` is what I needed. I was trying to accomplish it without ActiveSupport but this is still very useful. Thank you!